# Unable to add a text to an input field based on the returned Json value

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I have the following Script inside my View:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Server_VirtualCenterID").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        if ($(this).val() == "3") {
            $("#Server_VirtualCenterID").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        else {
            $("#Server_VirtualCenterID").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
        $("#Switch_RackID").change(function () {
            var idRack = $(this).val();
            $.getJSON("/Rack/LoadDataCenterByRack", { id: idRack },
            function (RackData) {
                var select = $("#Switch_TMSRack_DataCenter_Name");
                select.empty();
                select.append(Text);

                });
            });
        });
       </script>
```

Which will call the following action method when the drop down list is changed:-

```
public JsonResult LoadDataCenterByRack(int id)
    {
      string datacentername = repository.FindRack(id).DataCenter.Name;

      var DCData = new { Text = datacentername, Value = datacentername };

        return Json(DCData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

But the return json will not be add as a text for the `Switch_TMSRack_DataCenter_Name` input field? can anyone advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `select.append(RackData.Text)` instead of `select.append(Text)`

Provide `RackData` is a JSON. As `RackData` is response data. You need to fetch `Text` property from `RackData`.

I would suggest to simply use

```
$("#Switch_TMSRack_DataCenter_Name").val(RackData.Text);
```